# Javascript beginner asking for code enhancement - Biggest number task

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript from a scratch and one online course gave me a quest to find out the biggest number from given field of numbers using javascript.

This is what I made:

```
function biggest(array) {
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
    if (array[i] >= array[0]) {
      array[0] = array[i];
    }
  }
  else {
    if (array[i+1] >= array[0]) {
      array[0] = array[i+1];
    }
  }
}
  return array[0];
}

var array = [10,12,15,3,5,22,2];
console.log(biggest(array));
```

I made it on [codepen here](http://codepen.io/chlapecek/pen/MyNWgW).

Could you please tell me **how to make this function** even **better** ? 
I believe it's not the most efficient way, the execution context has to keep the whole array for the whole period of time, but I think that the deletion of some indexes could add on the process time.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: This belongs on code review. Good for you for wanting to improve your code! http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks, I should have known about the feature

Comment: I believe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make first value maximum and then check any value bigger than that, replace with the previous maximum value with the current maximum value.

Like this:

```
var max = array[0];
for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (max < array[i])
       max = array[i];
}
  return max;
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/rvgrd7m4/)**</kbd>

Comment: To make it even better, you could avoid calculating the length of the array on every iteration: `for(var i = 1, l = array.length; i < l; i++)`

Comment: *array.length* @blex

Answer (score 4):

Performance almost never matters. Especially in Javascript. It's more important to write code that is readable and maintainable.

Your code modifies the array, which makes the second one not possible, because after a call of biggest() the array is different.

I would suggest something like this:

```
function biggest(array)
{
     return array.reduce((acc, curr) => acc < curr ? curr : acc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have marked the answer from Anik above, because of the provided code that I understand. But what you wrote about the readability and maintainability really left something in me and I see now what's wrong with my code.

Comment: @Adam Rajnoha reduce calls a function recursive on an array. The first parameter is the result of all function calls ealier, the second one is the current value. Here is a very good explanation: https://youtu.be/Wl98eZpkp-c

Comment: FYI, you're missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Its a good practice not to modify the given parameters in a function. Iterate through array and if the current item is greater than max so far ; set max to the current item. And for also initialization set the first item to max too  Here is the function:

```
function biggest(givenArray){
    givenArray = givenArray || [];
    var max = undefined;
    for(var i = 0; i < givenArray.length; i++){
         if(max === undefined || max < givenArray[i]){
             max = givenArray[i];
        } 
    }
   return max;
}
```

Comment: `function biggest(givenArray){
    var max = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < givenArray.length; i++){
         if(max < givenArray[i]){
             max = givenArray[i];
        } 
    }
   return max;
} ` will work just fine.

Comment: Well if all the items in the array are negative numbers it wont work.

Comment: That is correct. However, if all members of the array are negative numbers, it would change the case. Wouldn't we be looking for max negative instead, or would we? Because, in this case it would be returning the minimum negative number instead. :) It seems that using the array sort provided with a sort rule and a second argument enabling us to also customize the return, would be the best way to go. But that always comes as a second thought. Anyway, this one needs a vote-up.

Comment: Well if all the items are negative then it would again return the largest item in the array, this would break if only `givenArray` is undefined =) Let me correct that =)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to simply find the *biggest* number in a set (array), the following would be the most simplistic approach IMO (using ES6):

```
function biggest(array) {
    return Math.max(...array)
}
biggest([10, 12, 15, 3, 5, 22, 2]) // 22
```

[Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) will not accept an array as an argument, so we'll pass a [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), which allows the *expression* (array) to be expanded into separate arguments. This allows us to use `Math.max()` without error.

Alternatively, we would use [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to achieve the same output.

```
function biggest(array) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, array)
}
biggest([10, 12, 15, 3, 5, 22, 2]) // 22
```

Using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) we can offer (arguably) an even greater level of function clarity, while still using the *spread operator* to build our argument list within `Math.max()`:

```
const biggest = array => Math.max(...array)
biggest([10, 12, 15, 3, 5, 22, 2]) // 22
```